# This quick sort code is not working in offline compiler, but it is working on sites like Programiz and GDB online, can I know why?

Tags: c, quicksort

I was getting blank screen in Devc++ and some random characters in turboc++.
I have to use turbo c++ in lab exam so please help in that way.
Here is code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void swap(int *xp, int *yp)
{
    int temp = *xp;
    *xp = *yp;
    *yp = temp;
}
int part(int arr[],int l,int u)
{
    int s=l,e=u;
    int pivot=arr[l];
    while(s<e)
    {
        while(arr[s]<=pivot)
        {
            s++;
        }
        while(arr[e]>pivot)
        {
            e--;
        }
        if(s<e)
        {
            swap(&arr[s],&arr[e]);
        }
    }
    swap(&arr[l],&arr[e]);
    return e;
}
int quick(int arr[],int l,int u)
{
    int loc;
    if(l<u)
    {
    loc=part(arr,l,u);
    quick(arr,l,loc);
    quick(arr,loc+1,u);
    }
}
void printArray(int arr[], int n)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
int main()
{
    int arr[] = {0,1,27,8},n;
    clrscr();
    n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    quick(arr,0,n);
    printArray(arr,n);
  
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add the source into your question, external resources tend to vanish. Most probably you have Undefined Behavior or something similar. Do you write into all your variables before you read them?

Comment: Compiler warning: `quick()` must return a value. But with MSVC after removing `clrscr()` the correct output is given, and no warnings.

Comment: Yes, I initialized all variables and the code works in online compilers just doesn't work on devc++ and turboc++

Comment: `arr[e]` may be beyond the end of the array. Perhaps `quick(arr,0,n);` should be `quick(arr,0,n-1);`?

Comment: You've named the parameters to `quick()` `l` for lower and `u` for upper. So they're presumably within the array but you're passing `n` for upper where `n` is the array length, not the upper index.

Comment: Thanks @IanAbbott, the code now works properly.

Comment: Good catch, it is clear from `quick(arr,l,loc); quick(arr,loc+1,u);` that the second argument is inclusive.

Comment: Thanks everyone for answering. The issue was about quick function in main where the correct values should've been quick(arr,o,n-1) instead of quick(arr,0,n).

Comment: `quick(arr, 0, n - 1);` is not enough. https://godbolt.org/z/sWE8dYqYf - see how the `while (arr[s] <= pivot)` loop ends up using `arr[4]` which is out of bounds?

Comment: @TedLyngmo This issue is not arising in the compilers which I am using but I get what you are saying. How can I fix that?

Comment: _"This issue is not arising in the compilers which I am using"_ - Doesn't matter. The program has undefined behavior so it could look likes its working while it's secretly deleting all your photos. _"How can I fix that?_" - Go through your algorithm, step through the program in a debugger to see what it does at every step and what the values of the variables are at every step.